# Google Apps Script ScriptDB is no longer in a consistent state

Tags: google-apps-script

The ScriptDBs for my scripts are no longer in consistent state. they are returning invalid result sets. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Saqib, can you log this issue on the Issue Tracker? https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list. Please include any code, reproduction steps and other details you have.

Comment: @ArunNagarajan, unfortunately (or fortunately) this issue is very very sporadic. Now I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the ScriptDB service was deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, same here. I am sporadically getting empty results back for queries, which then results in duplicates being in the database.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working normally.
What I had was my fault cause I was sending in the query an Integer and all was as String.